# Onclick event inheritance for child element?

Tags: events, inheritance, onclick

There is a div with onclick event. I don’t know where does that event attached. I put an image inside this div with jquery and when i click on image nothing depends, but if i click in this div but not on images than event happens. How can I make image to inherit that onclick event?

Comment: Look up the jquery "on" function, it allows you to bind events to new/dynamic content something along the lines of $("#img").on("click", function(){})

Comment: But i dont know what function to append, how can i see what function is appended to that parent div. It is appended somewhere deep in js, its WP theme and i will brake my brain till i find it.

Comment: Have you tried using dev tools and searched by the div selector of class or ID? There are definitely ways to find out, you just need to dig into it a bit, you may also wish to update your question with more details; like the bit about word press and maybe if its a particular plugin

Comment: It's part of wp theme, something like tabs, it's caled timeline there are round div's with text wich onclick swap content under it. event is atached in js file and it looks like

Comment: item.click(function(){
      if (( ! section.hasClass('active')) && ( ! running)) {
       running = true;
       items.each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
         $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
       });
       if (item.length) {
        item.addClass('active');
       }

Comment: and i dont know how to atach this event to image that is inserted inside this div ondocument ready by jquery

Comment: That function is 'inline' it has no function name you can call, but using the code I gave you above you can copy paste it in: $("#img").on("click", function(){PASTE IT HERE}) or you can pull that function out of the item.click stuff and make it a proper function